# Query Inside a redis model in yii2

Tags: activerecord, redis, yii2

I have created a redis model, which should store statistics like this:

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
use \yii\redis\ActiveRecord;
use \yii\redis\ActiveQuery;

class StatsModel extends ActiveRecord
{

    public function attributes()
    {
        return ['id', 'hits', 'user', 'ua', 'ip','os'];
    }
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ['user', 'required'],
            ['user','string'],
            ['ip', 'required'],
            ['ip', 'integer'],
            ['hits', 'integer'],
            ['ua','string'],
            ['os','integer']
        ];
    }
    public static function total_user_hits($username)
    {
        $query = new ActiveQuery($this);
        $query->find()->where('user = '.$user)->all();
    }
    public static function getDb()
    {

        return \Yii::$app->db_redis;
    }
}
```

Now, i'm trying to make a static function, which i can use, to count all thi `hits` value for specific `user` in redis. I'm creating an `$query = new ActiveQuery($this);` each time in the function, but can how can initiliase just one copy of the query to always use it? If i do it like class property:

`public $query = new ActiveQuery($this);`

I get error `expression is not allowed as field default value`

Comment: Why you want to do this? What is wrong with creating new instance for each query?

Comment: @rob006 isn't it resource wasting? This method should be called by ajax from the frontend to display notifications each 5-6 seconds, if there will be a lot of active users, i assume a lot of memory will be wasted to create this object each time.

Comment: No, it's not. `ActiveQuery` is mutable, using one instance of query will give you only bunch of bugs. If you care that much about performance you should not use active record in the first place.

Comment: And your code is incorrect - you should not use `$this` inside of static method.

Answer (score 1):

You should not reuse existing query object (unless you want to make query with the same conditions) - `ActiveQuery` is mutable, it means that previous queries may change its state:

```
$query = new ActiveQuery(StatsModel::class);
$result1 = $query->andWhere('user = 1')->all(); // 1 result

$result2 = $query->andWhere('user = 2')->all(); // no results
```

Second query will not return anything, since it will create condition like `WHERE user = 1 AND user = 2` which is always false.

If you're afraid about performance, you should not. Creating `ActiveQuery` object has negligible overhead. Creating objects in PHP is relatively cheap and `ActiveQuery` is quite lightweight - the most time consuming thing will be actual query to redis/db.